# From the command line, how do I tell if a particular VPN connection is up?

Tags: network, command-line, vpn

Suppose that I have multiple VPN connections configured in System Preferences/Network.

How do I tell if a particular one (identified by the service name in System Preferences/Network) is up, **on the command line** in OS X Mavericks?

Comment: "Netstat -i" will do it

Comment: `netstat -i` shows the interface name, which is just `ppp0`, not the service name as seen in System Preferences/Network.

Comment: you mean the SSID ?

Comment: use the "airport -I" for that, it will list the SSID name

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSID or WiFi. I'm talking about VPN connections, which could be tunnelled over wired LAN or WiFi alike.

If you configure a VPN connection in System Preferences/Network, you have to give it a service name, just like the rest of your network connections ("Wi-Fi", "Bluetooth PAN", "Thunderbolt Bridget", etc). I'm talking about *that* service name.

Comment: `system_profiler -nospawn SPNetworkDataType` Will list interfaces. If You add `-xml` it'll be printed in XML format, so that You can parse it.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Nice! This edges towards a complete solution. Given that the output of that command is in plist format, would it actually be available and queryable through the `defaults` command?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the network address range, you could use "ifconfig" and parse the output to see if an interface is up and running with an IP in the appropriate range.

Comment: That's actually what I would like to avoid. Given that the IP address is assigned by the VPN server, relying on an address range would not be the most reliable way.